# Is there an application handler (aka callback) for import-post?

Tags: scripting

In Blender 2.8's Python API I'm looking for a import-post application handler. I thought maybe the load-post app handler would work for both loading and importing, but that is not the case. I can't seem to locate any documented application handler for import-post. Does one exist?